# Pandas: sum values from column to unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
ID    time    coeff   category
111    12      1.5     shop
111    15      1.5       shop
222    12      0.8     shop
222    18      0.8     shop
```

I need to get

```
category    unique_users
 shop         2.3
```

If I try

```
result = df.groupby(['category']).agg({'ID': pd.Series.nunique}).rename(columns={ 'member_id': 'unique_users'}).reset_index()
```

I get `2`, because it returns unique of `df.ID`. How can I sum values in `df.coeff` for unique `df.ID`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [2314]: (df.groupby('category')
              .apply(lambda x: x.groupby('ID').coeff.first().sum())
              .reset_index(name='unique_users'))
Out[2314]:
  category  unique_users
0     shop           2.3
```

Answer (score 4):

By using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates(['ID','category']).groupby('category').agg({'coeff':'sum'})
    Out[763]: 
              coeff
    category       
    shop        2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do what you want:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID']).groupby(['category']).agg(sum).drop(['ID', 'time'], axis=1)

Out[133]: 
          coeff
category       
shop        2.3
```