# Sum unique values by group with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I got a dataframe like this:

```
data = {
    'YEAR' :    [2018,2018,2017,2018,2018,2018],
    'SEASON':   ['SPRING', 'SPRING', 'WINTER', 'SPRING', 'SPRING', 'SPRING'],
    'CODE':     ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'BUDGET':   [500,200,300,4000,700,0],
    'QUANTITY': [1000,1000,1000,2000,300,4000]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

'''
   BUDGET CODE  QUANTITY  SEASON  YEAR
0     500    A      1000  SPRING  2018
1     200    A      1000  SPRING  2018
2     300    A      1000  WINTER  2017
3    4000    B      2000  SPRING  2018
4     700    C       300  SPRING  2018
5       0    D      4000  SPRING  2018
'''
```

For each **CODE** I got its correct **BUDGET** quantity, *but* unfortunately on the **QUANTITY** column I got the total quantity for that code within every [Year, Season].

I'm working on a function to aggregate my dataframe at different levels given as input: for example I'm giving the function a list like

```
my_list = [
  ['YEAR']
  ['YEAR', 'SEASON']
]
```

and the function will output a series of dataframes grouped by each sublist.

The problem here is I can aggregate **CODE** with *pd.Series.nunique* and I can *sum* the **BUDGET** column, but if I *sum* also the **QUANTITY** column I will obviously sum up more than I want. What I would need is some sort of *sumUniques* function by uniques **YEAR**, **SEASON**, **CODE**.

```
def sumUniques(x):
    return '???'

print(df.groupby(['YEAR', 'SEASON']).agg({
    'CODE': pd.Series.nunique,
    'BUDGET': sum,
    'QUANTITY' : sumUniques
}))

'''
             CODE  BUDGET QUANTITY
YEAR SEASON                       
2017 WINTER     1     300      ???
2018 SPRING     4    5400      ???


--> EXPECTED RESULT:
             CODE  BUDGET QUANTITY
YEAR SEASON                       
2017 WINTER     1     300      1000
2018 SPRING     4    5400      7300

'''
```

I'm asking myself which could be the best way to achieve this and I came upon [Zero's answer to *"Pandas: sum values from column to unique values"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46059606/7330125): I've tried it out, by it seems like either I'm not applying it correctly or that does not apply my problem, as it raises a **key error**:

```
print(df.groupby(['YEAR', 'SEASON']).agg({
    'CODE': pd.Series.nunique,
    'BUDGET': sum,
    'QUANTITY' : lambda x: x.groupby('CODE').QUANTITY.first().sum()
}))

'''
KeyError: 'CODE'
'''
```

I wonder what's the best way to make this work, hope this will be of help for others too!

Comment: If your question was addressed, please accept the answer that helped you. Thanks.

Comment: I add new solution with timings, can you check it with your real data?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on your comments, a slightly more involved procedure is required to get your result. The solution for `QUANTITY` is very similar to how it is in jezrael's answer with `apply`, so thanks to him.

```
df

   BUDGET CODE  QUANTITY  SEASON  YEAR
0     500    A      1000  SPRING  2018
1     200    A      1000  SPRING  2018
2     300    A      1000  WINTER  2017
3    4000    B      2000  SPRING  2018
4     700    C       300  SPRING  2018
5       0    D      4000  SPRING  2018
6     500    E      1000  SPRING  2018

f = {
        'CODE' : 'nunique', 
        'BUDGET' : 'sum'
}

g = df.groupby(['YEAR', 'SEASON'])
v1 = g.agg(f)
v2 = g.agg(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates('CODE', keep='first').QUANTITY.sum())

df = pd.concat([v1, v2.to_frame('QUANTITY')], 1)

df

             CODE  BUDGET  QUANTITY
YEAR SEASON                        
2017 WINTER     1     300      1000
2018 SPRING     5    5900      8300
```

Comment: I believe your 2018 Spring grouping Quantity should be 7300 and not 8300.

Comment: Disregard.  I see you changed the original df.

Answer (score 10):

Use `groupby` + `apply` with a custom function:

```
def f(x):
   a = x['CODE'].nunique()
   b =  x['BUDGET'].sum()
   c = x.drop_duplicates('CODE').QUANTITY.sum()
   #Or:
   #c = x.groupby('CODE').QUANTITY.first().sum()
   return pd.Series([a,b,c], index=['CODE','BUDGET','QUANTITY'])


print (df.groupby(['YEAR', 'SEASON']).apply(f) )

             CODE  BUDGET  QUANTITY
YEAR SEASON                        
2017 WINTER     1     300      1000
2018 SPRING     4    5400      7300
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['YEAR', 'SEASON']).agg({ 'CODE' : 'nunique', 'BUDGET' : 'sum'})
s = df.drop_duplicates(['YEAR', 'SEASON','CODE']).groupby(['YEAR', 'SEASON'])['QUANTITY'].sum()

df = df1.join(s.rename('QUANTITY'))
print (df)
             BUDGET  CODE  QUANTITY
YEAR SEASON                        
2017 WINTER     300     1      1000
2018 SPRING    5900     5      8300
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
a = ['WINTER', 'AUTUMN', 'SUMMER', 'SPRING']
b = list('ABCDEFGHIJKL')
c = range(1990, 2018)

data = {
    'YEAR' :    np.random.choice(c, N),
    'SEASON':   np.random.choice(a, N),
    'CODE':     np.random.choice(b, N),
    'BUDGET':    np.random.randint(1000,size= N),
    'QUANTITY': np.random.randint(1000,size= N)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df.head())
   BUDGET CODE  QUANTITY  SEASON  YEAR
0      92    L        95  SUMMER  2003
1     961    A       696  SPRING  1992
2     481    G       351  WINTER  1992
3     296    A        51  SPRING  1996
4     896    G        58  AUTUMN  2007
```

---

```
def cols(df):
    f = {
        'CODE' : 'nunique', 
        'BUDGET' : 'sum'
        }

    g = df.groupby(['YEAR', 'SEASON'])
    v1 = g.agg(f)
    v2 = g.agg(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates('CODE', keep='first').QUANTITY.sum())

    return pd.concat([v1, v2.to_frame('QUANTITY')], 1)

def jez2(df):
    df1 = df.groupby(['YEAR', 'SEASON']).agg({ 'CODE' : 'nunique', 'BUDGET' : 'sum'})
    s = df.drop_duplicates(['YEAR', 'SEASON','CODE']).groupby(['YEAR', 'SEASON'])['QUANTITY'].sum()
    return df1.join(s.rename('QUANTITY'))


def f(x):
   a = x['CODE'].nunique()
   b =  x['BUDGET'].sum()
   c = x.groupby('CODE').QUANTITY.first().sum()
   return pd.Series([a,b,c], index=['CODE','BUDGET','QUANTITY'])


print (df.groupby(['YEAR', 'SEASON']).apply(f))

print (jez2(df))
print (cols(df))
```

---

```
In [46]: %timeit (df.groupby(['YEAR', 'SEASON']).apply(f))
1 loop, best of 3: 674 ms per loop

In [47]: %timeit (jez2(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.31 s per loop

In [48]: %timeit (cols(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.88 s per loop
```

Comment: Your output is completely opposite. Check Code and Budget columns.

Comment: I don't understand either. SO is weird. I had downvotes for no reason as well. I guess someone took it back but I still have one there on my answer. What can you do, it happens.

Comment: I add some timings, it seems apply is fastest. But maybe with real data it is different.

Comment: OP already timed our answers, mine took around 2 seconds while yours took over 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, but I add another solution with `agg`, I think OP can test it and I think it will be faster, because different logic.